# Find a positive definite matrix with $a_{1,1}<0$

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples, positive-definite

> Find a matrix $A=[a_{i,j}]$ such that $A$ is positive definite and $a_{1,1}<0$.

It is not easy. In my opinion, there is no such matrix if the matrix dimension is even.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x = \left(\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{matrix}\right)$, then
$$x^TAx = \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}{a_{ij}x_ix_j}.$$
In particular, for $x = e_1 = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)$, we have
$$ e_1^TAe_1 = a_{11}.$$
If $A$ is positive definite, then $e_1^TAe_1$ is positive, and hence $a_{11}$ must be positive.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), saying that $\mathrm A \succ \mathrm O$ is equivalent to saying that all the *leading* principal minors of $\mathrm A$ are *positive*. Note that $a_{11}$ is the $1 \times 1$ leading principal minor. Thus, $a_{11} > 0$.

Therefore, a matrix $\mathrm A$ with $a_{11} < 0$ cannot be positive definite.